# Identifying Specialized bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, specialized-bikes

I need help identifying the specs of this Specialized bike. The frame is carbon fiber and has a Diverge logo, it's a mens bike. Bought mid last year. The tires were thinner track tires but changed for thicker tires for city use.

I got it as a gift but want to sell it now so I need to know specs. Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

Comment: Since this isn't a retro model, why don't you contact Specialized directly with a serial number and complete parts setup? They'll have the answer. If you want an answer from us, we're also missing the same critical info.

Comment: We don't give valuations as they're largely a matter of opinion, vary by location and quickly go out of date. As for identification, it's a Specialized Diverge -- have you looked at the specs of the 2017 and 2018 models to compare against what you have?

Comment: Note that I believe your model has an aluminum and not a carbon frame.  The carbon frames have a cut out on the seat tube for more tire clearance.  It’s likely a Diverge E5 Comp.

Comment: In some cultures its rude to sell a gift.  The item should be offered back to the giver first.

Answer (score 2):

As one of the commenters pointed out, this is likely a 2019 Specialized Diverge E5 Comp.  I'll leave a link to the specifics below, but basically this is an aluminum frame with a carbon composite fork, and it runs a Shimano 105 drivetrain, praxis alba crankset, and TRP dual piston mechanical disk brakes.

Your friendly bike shop guy,

Josh

[MY19 Spec Diverge E5 Comp](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/mens-diverge-comp-e5/p/128909)

Answer (score 1):

Given it has a carbon frame, suspension headset, and mechanical disk brakes it's probably a Diverge Sport: https://www.specialized.com/us/en/mens-diverge-sport/p/152240?color=239522-152240

There are no other models on the website with that combination of components.

Comment: Take a closer look at the picture, it has an aluminum frame. The carbon frames have a cut-out in the seat tube for the rear tire, the aluminum models do not.  It is probably the E5 comp.  Still a nice bike!

Comment: TBH I just went by the OPs title where he said it is carbon